# convert \x1d\xe3Gi%a\x00\x00\x00\x00 to 1de347692561

Tags: python-2.7

I use win7 and python 2.7.
 I want to convert \x1d\xe3Gi%a\x00\x00\x00\x00 to 1de347692561.
 How could I succeed in the conversion?

I have tried binascii.hexlify and codec.encode but all failed.[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: [`binascii.hexlify()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify)

Comment: this does not work

Comment: pls see the photo added

Comment: What are the input and output types? Please don't post screenshots of text. Post the text and format it as code instead. We can't copy and play with a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you don't hexlify the correct string, you hexlify `read_key_final`, which is derived from a string representation of the **list** `read_key_ascii_hex`. Therefore, you get

```
5b5c7831645c786533476925615c7830305c7830305c7830305c7830305d
 ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
 [ \ x 1 d \ x e 3 G i % a \ x 0 0 \ x 0 0 \ x 0 0 \ x 0 0 ]
```

try `read_key_ascii_hex = ''.join(i.decode("hex" for i in read_key))` instead (or two more `replace` calls to remove the brackets).

Answer (score 0):

This code works in both Python 2 and 3.

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = b'\x1d\xe3Gi%a\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(x)
'1de34769256100000000'
```